# Sharing processes and state in Flask + Gunicorn

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, gunicorn

I'm building a Flask application, consisting of two parts:

1. "Executor part": it gets a task and then execute it. The executor runs each task in a separate process due to the I/O work (2 socket connections). Only one task can be executed simultaneously (because they're using shared resources).
2. "Flask part": it provides to users control of the executor, committing tasks, reads the state of executor, etc.

The bridge between these two parts is the global object of TaskExecutor.
TaskExecutor.py

```py
def execute(task, reporter):
    conn = ResourceConnection(...)
    with conn as c:
        for f in task:
            func, args = f
            func(c, **args)
            reporter.report(...)  # updates state of execution


class TaskExecutor:
    def __init__(self):
        self._process = Process()
        self.reporter = Reporter()  # some variables

    def _is_alive(self):  # checks if the process is alive
        ...

    def _graceful_term(self):  # stops the process
        ...

    def start(self, task):
        if self._is_alive():
            self._graceful_term()
        self._process = Process(target=executor,
                                args=(task, self.reporter))
        self._process.start()

    def stop(self):
        ...
```

Controlbp.py

```py
control_bp = Blueprint('control', __name__, url_prefix='/control')

task_executor = TaskExecutor()

@control_bp.route('/demo', methods=["POST"])
def run_demo():
    task_executor.start([demo_func, {"a": 42}])
    return ""

@control_bp.route('/state')
def get_state():
    return task_executor.reporter.to_json()
```

Right now, in Flask dev environment, everything works fine.
I'd started to look at Gunicorn, and it doesn't seem clear if only one task in my "executor part" will run concurrently and will it work at all. Gunicorn seems to spawn child processes (workers), which will have shared memory, which only shared to read, not write or execute. Am I wrong, or I need to modify the bridge somehow? How Gunicorn spawn workers with shared objects?
If this important, my app will have only 1-2 users simultaneously.